# SQLITE3 query condition

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm new to sqlite3 and have hit a bit of a wall with my database. I don't really have anybody else to ask so a friend recommended I post here to try get a bit of help.

Say I have two tables

restaurants:

```
Restaurant  Location  Chef
'All Beef'  'London'  'Bob'
'All Lamb'  'Paris'   'Mike'
'All Pork'  'Berlin'  'Jill'
'All Veg'   'London'  'Heather'
```

chefs:

```
Name      Gender     Place_Of_Birth
'Bob'     'Male'     'London'
'Mike'    'Male'     'Paris'
'Jill'    'Female'   'London'
'Heather' 'Female'   'Berlin'
```

'How many restaurants are there in London with chefs that were not born there?'

Just looking for a point in the right direction, thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried something yet? Try some queries, and let us know why the result is not what you expect, then some people here will help you on that.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get this :

```
$sql = SELECT count(*),R.restaurant //get the count and restaurant name
FROM restaurants R, chefs C
WHERE C.place_of_birth <> 'London' and //making sure place of birth is not london
R.chef = C.name;//linking both tables by name(chef)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also query like this:

```
select count(*) from restaurants 
INNER JOIN chefs ON restaurants.Chef = chefs.Name
where restaurants.Location = 'London' AND chefs. Place_Of_Birth != 'London'
```